# Convert Array to JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am trying to replace the dropdown in to the multiselect drop down

```
<select name="molecularMethod" class="form-control" ng-model="request.molecularMethod" multiple>
```

It works perfectly fine. But it generates the array when selected,like below

```
MOLECULARMETHOD : (2) ["Am", "BAC"]
```

but I am trying to convert this in to JSON so I can use in to the Odata POST Body

So used the

```
JSON.stringify($scope.request.molecularMethod)
```

Now I see

```
MOLECULARMETHOD : "["Am","BAC"]"
```

I am trying to get as

```
MOLECULARMETHOD : "Am,BAC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code to get output as "Am,BAC":

`($scope.request.molecularMethod).join(",");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
var MOLECULARMETHOD = MOLECULARMETHOD.substring(1, MOLECULARMETHOD.length-1);
MOLECULARMETHOD = MOLECULARMETHOD .replace(/"/g, "");
```

Comment: `$scope.request.molecularMethod` holds the array and I cannot perform substring directly on `$scope.request.molecularMethod`